# text in <h1> tag not visible in ion-content element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to make single page application using ionic .But why I am not able to see contend in  tag.my **contend** text is hidden  why ?

**code**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvYdNM

```
<ion-view>
      <ion-header-bar class=" bar bar-positive">
          <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>                 
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
          <h1>contend</h1>
      </ion-content>
      <ion-footer-bar class=" bar bar-footer bar-positive">
           <h1 class="title">Fotter!</h1>
      </ion-footer-bar>
  </ion-view>
```

**Answer :**

```
<ion-view>
      <ion-header-bar class=" bar bar-positive test">
          <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>    
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
          <h1>contend</h1>
      </ion-content>
      <ion-footer-bar class=" bar bar-footer bar-positive">
           <h1 class="title">Fotter!</h1>
      </ion-footer-bar>
  </ion-view>

<style>

    .test {
     border: 1px solid red;
     position: relative!important;
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.bar` is set to be `position: absolute` so `<ion-header-bar>` is taken out of normal flow. This causes `<ion-content>` to move to the top of the window and be covered up by `<ion-header-bar>`.

Comment: so what is the solution to take contend below the header

Answer (score 1):

The content is actually inside the page. Your **CSS** needs to be fixed. Just a proof that its there : [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/prashant_ghimire/6p1xcw43/1/)

```
<h1 align="center" style="padding-top:150px">contend</h1>
```